# How to get com.google.gwt.user.client.Window maxWidth and maxHeight in GWT

Tags: gwt

How can I get `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window` `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` in GWT please ? I can just call `Window.getClientWidth()` and `Window.getClientHeight()` but it don't tell me if it's the maximum width and height of my Window :/

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do :

```
public native int getScreenWidth() /*-{
  return screen.width;
}-*/;

public native int getScreenHeight() /*-{
  return screen.height;
}-*/ ;
```